# Using scrolling up from pageload to reveal additional content

Tags: design-patterns, scrolling

There are certain sites have a pattern where the page loads, and then if a user scrolls up, additional content is presented. I know that [NBCNews.com does this with certain pages](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/3032072/ns/business/), and I've been told the Facebook timeline has a similar behavior.

I'm interested to find out whether this technique is well suited for showing non-essential content or navigation while not pushing the main content of the page down too much.

Comment: I've removed your request for examples of this technique. As a Q&A website we need questions that solicit actual answers, but if you request examples then you'll end up with answers just giving the odd example here and there (as you can tell with the answers recieved). Such answers do not solve the question so none of them can be marked as the 'Correct' one. Do you have a specific scenario where you are considering using this technique?

Answer (score 6):

Vimeo does this. When you load up a video page, you can scroll up to see related videos

Here is an [example from vimeo](http://vimeo.com/63653873).

They include a "More videos" link which scrolls the page up for you, which is a nice way to make you notice this functionality

I really like it on Vimeo, but I'm not so sure about that NCBNews.com example

Answer (score 2):

[Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) achieves the same effect as "scrolling up for additional content", but without actually having the user scroll up. Instead, all of the additional content is hidden in a pull down menu, which when opened pushes the rest of the body content downwards (as against most other sites (e.g. [Asus](http://eee.asus.com/en/)) where the pull down menu merely overlap the body content). Compare this with the Vimeo example from Steve's answer.

**EDIT :**
In the process of getting an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083329/how-to-obtain-non-uniformly-scrolling-elements-and-layered-curtain-like-backgr), I stumbled upon [Unfold](http://unfold.no/) -- a site that loads right into the middle of the page, and the user can scroll either way. In fact, it even loops around the scrolling! So if the user starts by scrolling all the way up first, he's going to end up at the bottom of the page eventually! Wicked!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested to find out whether this technique is well suited for showing non-essential content or navigation while not pushing the main content of the page down too much.

I would argue with this reasoning. Since, when you finally do open the container, the content of the main page is pushed down.

Rather, I would call it an **interesting/serendipitous interaction**. It is a novel interaction and the usability/discoverability is debatable. Take the vimeo example, you can argue that they wanted to keep the more videos or top and give more focus to the community aspect (comments, etc.) But, at the same time they wanted to keep the video at the top of the landing page(?). So, by using this interaction they were able to achieve their goals. They could've done another layout, but, this is what they decided to go with.

Answer (score 1):

With the 'twitter update model' it depends on how important the main content is. If its critical, it should probably be on another part of the page where it can live in isolation. However there is a great example of main content presented at the top with new content pushing it down on linkedin. Personally I find the mixing in rolling content and content updated at distinct intervals or 'main content' jarring.

However if you are talking about scroll-up content as a static bar like, vimeos related video or the search option on evernote mobile, than its more than acceptable to push down the main content as its never pushed very far away.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone, in the "Contacts" view of the phone app:
Scrolling up reveals your own phone number.